# How can i pass special character like "#", "^" in http.post url as parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While passing special characters like `#`, `^` in `http.post url`, it is returning as bad request.

```
$http.post("requestFormDataInsert.jsp?manager=" +$scope.managerName+ "&productName="+ $scope.productName+ "&productVersion="+ $scope.versionNumber+ "&expectedDate="+ $("#datepicker1").val()+  "&description=" +$scope.description+ "&requestType="+$scope.requestType ).then( function( resp ){
    $scope.requestId = resp.data;
    alert("Your response has been updated successfully")
    $location.path('/');
});
```

Suppose we have some parameters here which contains as `#` (hash) or `^` characters so it is telling as `bad request`.

Comment: you have to encode your `parameters` while adding it to the `post` request.

Comment: probably with [URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: Means how to encode it and how to decode it in server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode your params. You can encode them manually by using [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or just add them into the param section on your request. In that way your params get serialized and encoded automatically.

```
$http({
  url: 'requestFormDataInsert.jsp',
  method: 'POST',
  params: {
    manager: $scope.managerName,
    productName: $scope.productName,
    productVersion: $scope.versionNumber,
    expectedDate: $("#datepicker1").val(),
    description: $scope.description,
    requestType: $scope.requestType
  }
}).then(function (result) {
});
```

Comment: Don't ever do it manually, if the framework can handle this for your

Comment: How to get parameter in server side , i m using request.getParameter method to fetching but it is just returning null

Comment: @NishantSingh is this a new question? Please create a new question "how to access get params on post request in Java" and may mark this answer as right since this is solving the issue you asked for? Please link your new question here and we will help you. Thanks